# componentDidUpdate not being called in mounted enzyme test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test the following component:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot){
 if (this.props.location.pathname.split('/')[1] !== prevProps.location.pathname.split('/')[1]) {
  for(var i in this.props.moduleList) {
    if(this.props.moduleList[i].Name.replace(/\ /g,'') === this.props.location.pathname.split('/')[1]) {
      this.props.setModule(this.props.moduleList[i], null);
    }
  }
}
```

}

After some research on stackoverflow, came across this answer but getting the following error:

```
  expect(received)[.not].toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Here is the test file

```
beforeEach(() => wrapper = mount(<BrowserRouter><Component {...baseProps} /></BrowserRouter>));


 it(`should call the 'setModule' function when 'moduleList.Name' prop changes`, () => {

// test that the setModule wasn't called yet
expect(setModule).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

// now update the prop
wrapper.setProps({ location: { ...baseProps.moduleList, Name: "/otherpath" } });

// now check that the setModule was called
expect(setModule).toHaveBeenCalled(baseProps.moduleList);
});
```

Comment: what does debugger show you?

Comment: console.log(wrapper.debug()) ?  my render method

Comment: <ModuleMenuComponent location={{...}} moduleList={{...}} setTarget={[Function: mockConstructor]} setModule={[Function: mockConstructor]} module={{...}} moduleMenuDropdownOpen={true}

Comment: no, I'm talking about setting a breakpoint inside `componentDidUpdate` with your IDE to see actual values are compared.

Comment: Having a problem with my debug and configurations  on vsc

Comment: What version of enzyme are you running? Can you update?

Comment: "enzyme": "^3.8.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-15": "^1.2.0",

Comment: "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.5",

Comment: you ever come up with a solution? currently having the same problem in a similar situation